# Worklight Analytics and WAS Plugin

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, analytics, load-balancing

Can the worklight analytics server be loadbalanced using an IHS Server?

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/monitor/t_installing_op_analytics_liberty.html?lang=en

For example, if the Liberty server is at host.ibm.com on port 8080 and the context root is analytics, then the wl.analytics.url property is as follows:

wl.analytics.url=http://host.ibm.com:8080/analytics/data

Could the host here be a IHS Server with WAS plugin configured to balance requests across multiple Analytics nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this shouldn't be necessary.

Worklight analytics uses Elasticsearch under the covers. When an anayltics request comes in from Worklight, the data is sent to Elasticsearch which will automatically route the analytics data to the correct node as long as the nodes have been setup correctly.

I suggest reading more about how Elasticsearch clustering works to see if it would be necessary to add an additional load balancer.

Comment: And if that server is down?

Comment: If the server is down and it is the server listed under wl.analytics.url, then you'd have a problem. Elasticsearch can handle the load balancing, but for reliability it wouldn't be a bad idea to use the IHS server.